# Autofac: Is there a hidden debug feature?

Tags: autofac

I remember I have read somewhere here in SO (maybe I was dreaming) that I can enable a "hidden" debug feature of Autofac, so that it can give me more information on what Autofac is doing in the background.

I asked because I just encountered a bug in my project. After I have added the following code into my AutofacModule:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MainWindowViewModel).Assembly)
    .AssignableTo(typeof(ViewModelBase))
    .EnableClassInterceptors()
    .InterceptedBy(typeof(NotifyPropertyChangedInterceptor));
```

when compile, at:

```
using (var container = builder.Build())
{
    ...
}
```

Autofac throws:

`System.NotSupportedException was unhandled. Parent does not have a default constructor. The default constructor must be explicitly defined.`

But it didn't tell me which class does not have a default constructor (maybe I have missed something in the output window?). I ended up opened all my ViewModel classes one by one... to check if they have a default constructor.

So it would be wonderful for me if Autofac has a hidden debug feature. If not, is there an automatic way to find all classes which don't have a default constructor?

Thanks

(sorry for my English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this isn't an Autofac exception - it looks like it might be a WPF one? If you can get the call stack from the debugger when the exception is thrown it should offer a clue.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. I tried to reproduce the issue by removing the default constructors from all ViewModels, this time the debugger successfully caught all errors in the Error List.